# Flutter - Index in TabBar always null

Tags: flutter, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I would like to include a TabBar in the body of a Scaffold (see picture) and then dynamically change the displayed widget below, but without using a TabBarView.

What would be the best way to solve this? I tried to implement this solution:

Read the current index of the TabBar and then use if condition in the body to display the corresponding widget.

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    new Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DefaultTabController(length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Profile'),   
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              // some other widgets
              Container(color: Colors.white,
                child: TabBar(controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.grey[700],
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                  tabs: myTabs,
               ],
                ),
              ),
              (_tabController?.index == 0) ?
              Container(child: Text(_tabController?.index.toString()))
              : Container(child: Text(_tabController?.index.toString())),
etc
```

Unfortunately, the value of _tabController?.index is always null. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want [ToggleButtons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html) instead.

Comment: Yes, actually think this should be way easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
from

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
}
```

to

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  _tabController.addListener(_tabSelect);
}

void _tabSelect() {
  setState(() {
    _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
  });
}
```

and, from

```
child: Column(
  ...
etc.
```

to

```
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    // some other widgets
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        labelColor: Colors.grey[700],
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        tabs: myTabs,
      ),
    ),
    Container(child: Text(_currentIndex.toString()))
  ],
),
```

[image: sample]